# Is * sign in frameSize.height*frameSize.width*nmixtures*(2 + 2*nchannels) means pointer or multiplication?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm never used C++ before, and I used OpenCV background subtraction MOG (Mixture of Gaussian) function in Python and I need to understand how the program works, [the OpenCV program](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/2.4.9/entry/modules/video/src/bgfg_gaussmix.cpp) line 123 there's command `bgmodel.create( 1, frameSize.height*frameSize.width*nmixtures*(2 + 2*nchannels), CV_32F );`.. I found the `.create` function is to allocate new data from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.11/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-create) with I assumed the parameter inside was `(int ndims, const int* sizes, int type)`, my question is what the * mean, is it multiplication or pointer?

Comment: Multiplication in this case.

Comment: `const int*` is a pointer type.

Comment: It has three use cases: the multiply operator, a pointer type declaration and dereferencing a pointer (making it a reference to the value the pointer is pointing to) - Here, only multiplications are involved.

Comment: @DieterLücking Can the multiply used together with pointer? If yes, how you can difference it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asterisk (*) has three use cases:

- The multiply operator: 2 * 3
- A pointer type declaration: int* p;
- Dereferencing a pointer (making it a reference to the value the
  pointer is pointing to): *p = 6;

Example:

```
int i;
int* p = &i; // Sorry, introducing another confusion, taking the address of i
*p = 2 * 3;

// Now *p and i have the value 6
```

In the question, only multiplications are involved

Comment: @user3794938 Please avoid the sir

Answer (score 1):

If we look at your example:

```
bgmodel.create( 1, frameSize.height*frameSize.width*nmixtures*(2 + 2*nchannels), CV_32F );
```

We want to know if the `*` is a pointer dereference or is it multiplication.  The form a a pointer dereference is

*pointer_type;

Which doesn't work here as every `*` is preceded by another variable.  If we look at the syntax for multiplication we have:

```
some_type * some_type;
```

Now that matches what we have with variables on each side of the `*`

Now lets say you want to dereference a pointer and multiply it with something.  To do that we will wrap the dereferencing in parentheses

```
some_type * (*pointer_type);
```